# Add material to text's bevel?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders

How do I add one material to the whole text (excluding the bevel) and a separate material that only applies to the bevel of the text?

For example, if I wanted to have this tile material on the whole text but gold on the text's bevels, how would I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: If you are using the Bevel Modifier, just set the material index to 1, in the modifier and add an additional material in to slot 1 with your Gold material after slot 0 which is your base material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: Go into Edit Mode, select some of the bevel's Faces, Click Select → Select Similar → Face Regions (this will select the text's bevel), create a new Vertex Group and assign these selected Faces to it, create a new Material Slot and assign these selected Faces (from the Vertex Group) to it, add a new Material to this new Material Slot and then you're done!

[image]

[image]

[image]